# Getting exception when trying to get the id of the new inserted row

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to get the primary key of the newly inserted record(which is an identity field)
The code snippet is as below

```
jdbcConnection=new JdbcConnection();
connection=jdbcConnection.getJdbcConnection();          
psmt=connection.prepareStatement("{call spCopyRecord(?)}",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
psmt.setInt(1, primarykey);
int status=psmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet generatedKeys=psmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if(generatedKeys != null &&generatedKeys.next()){
    newKey=generatedKeys.getInt(1);     
}
```

When I try to execute I am getting the exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
>   which points to executeUpdate statement.

I am using sqljdbc4 jar and SQL version is SQL server 2008.
Please help to fix this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think what you need is `.executeQuery()` ?

Comment: I don't think executing stored procedures is supported in combination with `getGeneratedKeys()`...

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
int status=psmt.executeUpdate();
```

Is'nt this actually a normal Select query?

Use [execute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) Or [executeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement must be executed before any results can be obtained.** for both execute() and executeQuery() :(

Answer (score 0):

Pass primary key column name as parameter to method PrepareStatement

prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames) ;

Use above Syntax to get preparestatement which give generated key

```
    jdbcConnection=new JdbcConnection();
    connection=jdbcConnection.getJdbcConnection();          
    psmt=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT QUERY",String[] UR_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NMAE);
    psmt.setInt(1, "params");
    int status=psmt.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet generatedKeys=psmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    while(generatedKeys.next())
   {
       String id = rs.getString(1); 
   }
```